# Preprocess a Paragraph when Added to Content Type

Tags: 8, paragraphs

I'm trying to disable a field in a Paragraph when it's added to a certain content type. Currently I'm using the following:

```
function my_module_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  switch($form_id) {
    case "node_content_type_form":
        $form['field_paragraph_content']['widget'][0]['subform']['field_paragraph_field']['#disabled'] = 'disabled';
      break;
  }
}
```

This works only after the node containing the paragraph has already been saved. When the paragraph in question is first added to the node the `field_paragraph_field` is not disabled.

How can I preprocess the Paragraph form when it is initially added to the content type so this field is always disabled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want it to work when creating a node and when editing the node, you should make the change using both the node add form and the node edit form:

```
mymodule_form_node_content_type_form_alter()

mymodule_form_node_content_type_edit_form_alter()
```

Or in your hook_form_alter in the question:

```
case "node_content_type_form":
case "node_content_type_edit_form":
```

There's another way to do this using hook_field_widget_form_alter():

```
function mymodule_field_widget_form_alter(&$element, FormStateInterface $form_state, $context) {

  if ($context['items']->getFieldDefinition()->getTargetBundle() == 'content_type' && $context['items']->getFieldDefinition()->getName() == 'field_paragraph_field') {
    $element['#disabled'] = TRUE;
  }

}
```